# Setup sbteclipse in eclipse for Play framework

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, eclipse-plugin, sbteclipse

I am new in Play framework. I followed by this [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Installing), installed successfully, but now I want to integrate project on eclipse. I viewed [official link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE#Eclipse) from play, but I do not understand where to write

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

and other steps.

I am using Mac Os X and Eclipse Luna.

Comment: I would suggest IntelliJ IDE . and you should check play doc more often. there you can find the solution easier (Scroll the link to the end to see the answer ).https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/BuildOverview

Comment: thanx for your the reply but question was too back and I moved in Spring Boot, and happy to use Spring boot

Comment: Oh ~ did not realize that , but  no much people using play nowadays, the community is not really active

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write it in the "project\plugins.sbt" file:

[image]

btw, if you are planning to use only java (as I see from the tag) then you can add this lines to the "build.sbt" file as well:

```
// Compile the project before generating Eclipse files,
// so that generated .scala or .class files for views and routes are present
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)

// Java project. Don't expect Scala IDE
EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java

// Use .class files instead of generated .scala files for views and routes
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)
```

**UPDATE**

**[@mkruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810109/mkurz)** gave a good advice as well:

> Use a text-editor and modify `project/plugins.sbt` and `build.sbt`
>   like described above and then run `activator eclipse` or `sbt eclipse`. 
>   You should then be able to import the project in Eclipse via
>   `File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace`

Comment: but how to import play project in eclipse ?

Comment: Use a text-editor and modify `project/plugins.sbt` and `build.sbt` like described above and then run `activator eclipse` or `sbt eclipse`. You should then be able to import the project in Eclipse via `File` -> `Import` -> `Existing Projects into Workspace`.

Comment: Thanks for this, the Play documentation is a little vague on this point but this got me going!

Comment: @ Randall Harleigh 
 Scroll down to the end Its highlighted with large font https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/BuildOverview